# Unable to get alert message while submitting form through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i am trying to submit a form using jquery but when i click on the submit button it just shows a blank page , now i know blank page means form has been submitted but that's not the behavior i want , i just want to show an `alert()` just for testing purpose but its showing a blank page

html :

```
 <c:forEach items="${cartlist}" var="product">
<form id="editcart" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" id="pid" name="pid" value="${product.pid}" hidden/>
    <input type="text" id="spid" name="spid" value="${product.sub_pid}" hidden/>
    <input type="text" id="cartid" name="cartid" value="${product.cart_id}" hidden/>
    <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="${product.quantity}" disabled/>
    <input type="button" value="Edit" class="enable" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" hidden/>
</form>
</c:forEach>
```

and the respective js is :

```
$(function () {
    $('.enable').click(function () {
        $(this).prev('#quantity').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next('.save').fadeIn();
    });
});

$('#editcart').submit(function () {
    alert();
    return false;

});
```

now the jquery `enable` `hide` all is working well and i have tested it multiple times , but the form is not submitting properly

Comment: Move the `submit` handler in `ready()`

Comment: You're looping through elements and creating the elements by using the same _id_. `id` should be **unique** in the document. Change the `id`s to `class`.

Comment: thnks again man ...this was really hurting me for a long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've said that `form` is submitted and a blank page is shown, that means the submit event handler is not working(i.e. `return false` in handler).

Because you haven't wrapped the `submit` event handler in `ready`, the event is not bound. Move the submit handler in ready and then it should work.

```
$(function () {
    $('.enable').click(function () {
        $(this).prev('#quantity').prop('disabled', false);
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next('.save').fadeIn();
    });

    $('#editcart').submit(function () {
        alert();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also, the `.enable` event handler can be refactor as follow:

```
$('.enable').click(function () {
    $('#quantity').prop('disabled', false); // ID is unique, no need to use prev()
    $(this).hide().next('.save').fadeIn(); // Chained
});
```

Comment: @amolsingh Make sure the id is not repeating